# How can I encrypt an LTspice model?

Tags: ltspice, model, encryption

I need to encrypt an LTspice MOS model in order to distribute it to my students. It is a .model not a .subckt.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 7):

LTspice doesn't care about extensions or the contents of the file -- when the `-encrypt` command line switch is used, it will encrypt the given file and delete (overwrite) the original (warning!).

For example you can create a file `test.txt` in which you can add whatever `.model` you want, like this fine diode:

```
.model dx d is=1m rs=10 n=10
```

Then the following command will encrypt the file:

```
/path/to/XVIIx64.exe -encrypt /path/to/test.txt
```

The new `test.txt` will have this contents (the old file will have been overwritten):

```
* LTspice Encrypted File
* 
* This encrypted file has been supplied by a 3rd
* party vendor that does not wish to publicize
* the technology used to implement this library.
* 
* Permission is granted to use this file for
* simulations but not to reverse engineer its
* contents.
* 
* Begin:
 D0 11 9F 94 F4 7F 5A 7E A6 7F 8C F9 7C 13 47 83
...
[similar lines]
...
 72 E3 CA 84 A9 2D 00 B1
* End 1909859199 3810717718
```

To use it just add this line to your schematic (`.lib` will do just fine, too):

```
.inc /path/to/test.txt
```

... and use the `.model` inside just like any other:

[image: test]

For comparison, the upper plot has the current through `D2`, which uses a visible `.model`, identical with the encrypted one. The plots are identical.

Comment: I just realized `D2` has `dx` as the name, but the traces are correct (the `.model` definition inside the schematic is the same as the one in the encrypted file).